# How do I remove the ownCloud overlay icons in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, owncloud

I would like to disable ownCloud's overlay icons over all the synced files when browsing around my local file system.  These icons include green ticks and red crosses depending on their current sync status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to rakekniven, a Forum Moderator at ownCloud:

*"on windows setup routine you can uncheck option for windows explorer overlay icon"*

-[source](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=26486)

Comment: Thanks for the reply...  Guess I'll uninstall first ready to reinstall.

Comment: Sometimes in Windows, you have a second option besides uninstall. In the Programs and Features Control Panel, there is sometimes an option called "Change" where it takes you through the initial setup and you can make changes. I don't know if OwnCloud offers this, but it might save you a little time to check.

Comment: @HighTechGeek OwnCloud does indeed offer this and it appears to have worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

run this with elevated privileges:

```
regsvr32 -u "C:\Program Files (x86)\ownCloud\shellext\OCOverlays_x64.dll"
```

`-u` disables the feature. omitting `-u`, you reactivate the feature. If you have a 32-bit Windows, the path changes appropriately.

Comment: Amazing! Just notice that the path might have changed in the meantime to `C:\Program Files (x86)\ownCloud\shellext_x64\OCOverlays.dll`

Comment: On my machine the path was `C:\Program Files\ownCloud\OCOverlays.dll`.